# View code inside Javascript file on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

previously i had javascript code right in the top of my view and it would work. Then, i learned that you can include the js file using yield and i did just that.

I had rails view code inside my javascript code like :

```
    $( "#exp-progressbar" ).progressbar({
            value: <%= ((@quest.end_time - Time.now).to_i * 100 ) / (@quest.duration * 60) %>
});
```

Now, after i do it with yield, i get an error when i do that in the separate js file. How can i do it now ?

Comment: What does the call to yield look like in your view? What is the error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution :

```
<% content_for :javascript_includes do %>
    <% if not @quest.nil? %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var experience = <%= ((@quest.end_time - Time.now).to_i * 100 ) / (@quest.duration * 60) %>;
            var quest_duration = <%= @quest.duration * 60 %>;
            var quest_timer = <%= (@quest.end_time - Time.now).to_i %>;
        </script>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "experience.js" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>

<% if flash[:error] %>
    <%= flash[:error] %><br><br>
<% end %>
```